# Creating a JUnit 5 test suite with multiple classes, setup, and cleanup

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am trying to create a JUnit test suite with actions that occur before tests run and after they complete. I have to copy some files from a resources folder contained in a project so they're available on the file system for testing, run tests, and then delete the temporary copied resources folder. (I know that otherwise I could just use getResourceAsStream(), but since some third-party dependencies can only read files if they're given file names as a string, this is how I have to do things.)

I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Ultimate) and JUnit 5.3.2. Both programs are installed and configured properly; I have used them without issue to create and run tests for some time.

However, I am running into problems creating this test suite. I have created the following test suite class:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestSuite.class);
        for (Failure failure: result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
            failure.getException().printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }

    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses({
        correct.package.path.Class1.class,
        correct.package.path.Class2.class
    })
    public static class TestSuite {

        @BeforeClass
        public static void setup() {
            System.out.println("Setting up");
        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void cleanup() {
            System.out.println("Cleaning up");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run MyTest, however, I get the following output:

```
Setting up
Cleaning up
initializationError(correct.package.path.Class1): No runnable methods
initializationError(correct.package.path.Class2): No runnable methods
false
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
... long ugly stack trace through JUnit classes ...
```

The paths to the Class1/Class2 classes containing testable methods (which are in different packages than the test suite class) are correct; I have triple-checked that. The testable methods in those classes also run just fine if I execute them independently.

Based on the current output, it looks like my suite is executing setup, then cleanup, then trying to find tests in the other classes and not finding them.

I have tried switching annotations from "BeforeClass" and "AfterClass" to "BeforeAll" and "AfterAll," moving the TestSuite class out of the MyTest class, and eliminating the setup and cleanup methods, without success. The only significant change I've seen is that if I switch annotations from "BeforeClass" and "AfterClass" to "BeforeAll" and "AfterAll" I get no messages from those methods on the console. I've also gone through StackOverflow; that's where I got all these potential solutions to try.

Also, I do not appear to have access to the "SelectPackages" annotation, the simple "Suite" annotation in lieu of "RunWith," or parameterized annotations. (Perhaps there's something I'm missing?)

Can anyone help me figure out why this test suite isn't working properly, please? I would appreciate any help you could give.

Thanks!

EDIT: Example tested class:

```
package correct.package.path;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class Class1 {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test Display")
    public void myTestMethod() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `@Nested` perhaps something you can use?

Comment: As for the temporary files, you can use `@TempDir Path myTempDir` (or if you prefer, `File` instead of `Path`). JUnit will create it for you, and clean it up when your tests ends.

Comment: @RobSpoor It appears so, but putting that annotation on the TestSuite class didn't change the error or the console output. Should I have put it somewhere else? I'm not very familiar with "Nested."

Comment: @RobSpoor It also doesn't look like I can use "TempDir," sounds like it would have been pretty cool.

Comment: @user16320675 A public class with no annotations on the class declaration, every method "public void" and annotated with "Test" and a "DisplayName."

Comment: Which `Test`? `org.junit.Test` or `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` ? I believe you are mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit 5...

Comment: @user16320675 org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

Comment: probably that is why the methods are not being recognized, try  the first one `org.junit.Test` since using JUnit 4 style (actually almost a JUnit 3 style)

Comment: @user16320675 What in the?!?! The import says JUnit 5. Somebody must have mislabeled it. Ugh! Thank you so much!